# Gradle vs Maven. Behavior with java Deprecated API usage

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have big project that uses **Maven** as building tool. It performs `install` operation for about ~30 min. I decided to move to **Gradle** since it's considered as faster building tool. But I faced a problem at `compileJava` task that looks like next :

```
[ERROR] [system.err] Note: /home/user/IdeaProjects/SomeClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

After such errors **Gradle** stops build process, but **Maven** completes `install` operation successfully.

So, my question is there a way to get rid of such **Gradle** behavior?

Comment: Replace your calls to deprecated methods.  They’re deprecated for a reason:  you should not be using them.

Comment: @VGR, I have a millions strings of code. Unfortunately, it's a big problem.

Comment: The compiler can show exactly which lines are the problem.

Comment: @VGR, I understand this, but I'll probably spend 3 years before I can fix that all.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208410/how-to-suppress-specific-lint-warning-for-deprecated-android-function) is how to disable deprecation checks for an android app.  It might also work for you.

Comment: It might be sufficient to add `options.compilerArgs.add('-Xlint:-deprecation')` to your build file’s compileJava section.

Comment: @VGR, I've already tried. No result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Java compiler does not treat deprecation warnings as compile errors. The Java plugin in Gradle obeys the same default, so you must have configured it to do so. In short, somewhere in your build, `javac` is given the option `-Werror`.

It could look like:

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs += ['-Werror']
}
```

If you do not want the build to fail on compiler warnings, this option needs to be removed from your configuration.

Comment: I get next `error: warning found and -Werror specified`

Comment: I edit my answer, made it clear that you have to find where that option is passed and causes the build to fail