# Deprecation of Drawable.getOpacity()

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

I am getting a deprecation warning for Drawable.getOpacity().

```
...\progressbar\MaterialProgressDrawable.java:304: warning: [deprecation] getOpacity() in Drawable has been deprecated
    public int getOpacity() {
               ^
1 warning
```

This class (MaterialProgressDrawable) extends Drawable and implements Animatable. Since getOpacity() is abstract in the parent class (`@Deprecated public abstract @PixelFormat.Opacity int getOpacity();`) I can't remove this method altogether either. What is the way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the way out?

Well, since the javadoc implies that the method is not used anymore, one solution would be to implement it as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public int getOpacity() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getOpacity is deprecated");
}
```

---

> Well, I'm running `./gradlew lint` so it should go in `lint.xml` with `severity=ignore`.  But I don't want to suppress every deprecation warning either ...

I'm not sure it is possible, but you could try reading:

- [How to suppress specific Lint warning for deprecated Android function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208410)

(It looks like the best you could do is suppress **all** deprecation warnings in specific classes or packages.)

Alternatively, you can selectively suppress specific deprecation warnings at the site where they are triggered; i.e. by adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotations as shown above.  For a once-off suppression this would be the simplest way.

If the deprecation warnings are coming from the Gradle `lint` task rather than the `javac` compiler, then you could use `//noinspection` comments instead of `@SuppressWarnings` annotations.  But according to [the documentation](http://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/features.md.html), `@SuppressWarnings` annotations are respected by the `lint` task.

Comment: Well, I'm running "./gradlew lint" so it should go in lint.xml with severity=ignore. But I don't want to suppress every deprecation warning either, so the task is to get the right xml incantation. Thanks!

Comment: Ummm ... doesn't a `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` work??